# kibana apache proxy failed

Tags: apache, proxy, kibana

folks.

I am trying to set up a reverse proxy for Kibana using Apache. I am not able to get it to work correctly.

Here are settings
====Apache 2.4.6 Proxy===== There is http:// in front of 192

ProxyRequest Off
Timeout 160
ProxyTimeout 160
ProxyPass /kibana 192.168.1.1:5601 retry=0
ProxyPassReserve /kibana 192.168.1.1:5601 retry=0
ProxyPassReserveCookiePath /kibana /

Kibana 4.1.6
kibana.yml

port: 5601
host: "192.168.1.1"
server.basePath: "/kibana"

When I accessed sample.com/kibana. Kibana fails to load with 404 errors due to missing the kibana path in the URL. For instance sample.com/styles/main.css (missing the kibana folder). It should be https://sample.com/kibana/styles/main.css

I think my reverse proxy set up is missing something.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument to ProxyPass should be a URL, something more like *http://192.168.1.1:5601/*